# Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down and proactively recycling - Azure function App

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, python-3.7

I am facing problem to run azure function app from my local. Its always getting error `‘’ Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down and proactively recycling”`.
Can anyone help.

This is simple Anonymous Azure function app developed in Python.

Log details:

```
Starting worker process failed
[2020-10-21T06:33:57.585] The operation has timed out.
[2020-10-21T06:34:37.897] Executing 'Functions.HttpTriggerFunctionApp' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=ebd05bff-d1a8-4847-84df-d971845636ee)
[2020-10-21T06:34:57.631] Starting worker process failed
[2020-10-21T06:34:57.634] The operation has timed out.
[2020-10-21T06:35:57.658] Starting worker process failed
[2020-10-21T06:35:57.661] The operation has timed out.
[2020-10-21T06:35:57.669] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down and proactively recycling
the Functions Host to recover
```

Comment: What are you doing inside the function? are pointing/connecting  to a a storage account or any other azure resources ?

Comment: @SatyaV:- No This is simple (default hello world ) azure function app

Comment: Is this [post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42379) helpful to your problem. It mentioned to downgrade VS code version.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @HuryShen:- I have checked this post, but didn't get any proper solution

Comment: @SatyaV:- We are not doing any database connection or any storage account. Its a simple hello world app fucntion

Answer (score 0):

@Bowman Zhu:-  Below are the the code which are we are using. **

> Same code, if i deploy to azure portal is working fine, but not
> working in my local?

**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```